# How to get a no-match for a pattern: regex not followed by another regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

This is obviously a simplified case, but what need is a regex that would give no match for `aabb|bbaa` but would work fine for `aabb` (not followed by `|...`).

A regex like `[ab]+(?!\|[ab]+)*` is pretty close, but it still matches `aabb` from `aabb|bbaa`, while I would like to get *no match at all* in that case.

Using start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) anchors is not allowed.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the wrong `Matcher` method. Use `Matcher#matches()` to match the entire input sequence.

Comment: I'm using Matcher#find() and then taking first group found as a result. I cannot change that.

Comment: You cannot change the method used, nor add `^$` anchors? What's with the seemingly-arbitrary restrictions? Is this an interview question?

Comment: Worse, it's a legacy code :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule that you must express everything in a single regular expression. It also makes the code unreadable. I would suggest something like

```
not (matches "aabb\|bbaa") and (matches "aabb")
```

If you insist, you can use

```
([ab]+)(\|[ab]+)*
```

and discard the match if the second group is not empty.

Comment: I'm only allowed to change the regex. The code referring to it, uses Matcher#find() and groups to find the matching text.

Comment: Please tell the people who established those rules that they are a bunch of <insert favorite swearing here> idiots.

Comment: Still, if this is like you have a configuration file or some such, with deny and allow rules, then first use `deny a\|b` followed by `allow a`. If you only have allow rules, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do need anchors in your lookahead, one way or the other

```
 [ab]+(?=[^ab]*\z)
```

In more general, where `a` and `b` are arbitrary subexressions, you need:

```
 (?:a|b)+(?=(?s:(?!a)(?!b).)*\z)
```

Which should ***always be written in `/x` mode*** for legibility and maintainability:

```
 (?x)           # enable white space and comments

 (?: a          # any a
   | b          # or b
 ) +            # repeated once or more, preferring more

 # now a lookahead assertion
 (?=
     (?s: (?!a)  # not a coming right up at this point
          (?!b)  # nor b coming  right up at this point
          .      # any single code point
     ) *         # repeated zero or more times
     \z          # anchored to the end of the string
  )
```

Comment: There is just one pattern here. I simplified it to `[ab]+`, but if referred as `p` the question would be: how to make Matcher#find() return false for `p\|p` but true for `p`. Notice escaped `|`.